# Adding thousands separator to variable with a period in its name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, separator

I'm not too familiar with Javascript so there's probably a really simple solution to this. All I want to do is add comma thousands separators to the output of this function:

```
function() {
return '$' + this.value;
}
```

So, for instance $100000 will display as $100,000. My problem is that I don't know how to deal with the variable this.value because of the period.

I tried:

```
function numberWithCommas(this.value) {
    return '$' + this.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

My guess is that **this.value.toString()** is not proper syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to far? SO isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you:

```
var n = 1123456789.123
n.toLocaleString()
"1,123,456,789.123"
```

See more: [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

2. You can use: [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) - it is very powerful

And: in the future, you really research and try again and again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
function numberWithCommas() {
    return '$' + this.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```